# stringtokenizer and an unknown variable type

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I’m currently working on a project in which I stream in a text document and tokenize it. The only problem is the types in the text document is unknown, is there any way to check what variable type it is before I set it to a variable in the program?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: When you say "the types in the text document is unknown", do you mean you don't know whether the text stream is UTF-8 or ASCII or UTF-16? or do you mean the text contains numbers as well and you want to save numbers as numbers and text (non-numeric) strings as plain text?

Comment: No, it isn't homework, and yes it contains a line of both strings and number, I want the code to figure out what it is then apply it to the right variable type.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the type information is not contained in the text stream. For example, imagine the tokeniser encounters the following token:

```
47
```

What type does this have? It could be a String (`"47"`), a byte, an int, a long, a float or a double. All of those types could have produced that token, so there is no way to tell what the type was before it was printed.

When you parse a file, *you* should already know what types to expect, and give an error if it does not match.

The [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class only gives you back Strings. If you are expecting Strings, you can just save them to a variable. If you are expecting another type, you must parse it. For example, if you read the string `"47"`, then you should run it through [Integer.parseInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). This will either return an int (e.g., `47`), or throw a NumberFormatException if it didn't match. You might want to catch NumberFormatException and give the user an error, since the text file didn't match what you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you, It makes sense, but I thought there was a method of some sort to tell what the next token was, because I only saw hasMoreTokens();

Comment: Nope. StringTokenizer deals only with splitting strings into words. As you see from my answer, it has nothing to do with converting them into meaningful values (I had to use Integer.parseInt to do that). `hasMoreTokens` just tells you if there are more words left before the end of the string.